# Reduce Delphi Installation Size

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, delphi-xe6

I'm currently in charge of maintaining a very old 3rd party component for Delphi.

I need to support every Delphi version since Delphi 7 onwards.

I noticed that from Delphi XE6, each installation takes between 20-25 GB each.
And all I need is to run my component against it in a batch using FinalBuilder.

I see that most of the space is taken up in the `Lib` directory with this distribution:

- android 5.7GB
- iosDevice 3.8GB
- iossimulator 4.1GB
- osx32 1.2GB
- win32 2.22GB
- win64 4.08GB

Since I won't use anything related to developing for either Android or iOS, is it safe to just delete these folders?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier not to install the platform support for the platforms that you don't require?

Answer (score 3):

No it is not safe to just delete those folders.

You see when you install Delphi there are certain values written into your system registry telling Delphi IDE where it could find the files/packages needed for those features. So if you go and simply delete these folders upon launch Delphi IDE will still try to load those packages that no longer exists because you deleted them. Most likely result would be IDE failing to start properly or keep crashing.

Now if you don't need all those features for your component development you could install your Delphi using Custom installation where you can chose which features to install and which not.